# Union type assignment issue with React/Redux/Typescript setup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, union-types

I do have a pretty specific problem with an application setup utilising React, Redux and Typescript.

I planned on simplifying my reducers by following [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/redux-without-switch-cases-and-some-other-tips-6a3d27157da6) from medium and up to this point (where I have troubles working out the correct types) it works out pretty nicely.

---

Here is the `reducerFactory` implementation with all generic types I created:

*reducerFactory.ts*

```js
export interface ActionHandler<S, A> {
    [actionType: string]: GenericReducer<S, A>
}

export type GenericReducer<S, A> = (state: S, action: A) => S

const reducerFactory = <S, A extends { type: string }>(
    initialState: S,
    handlers: ActionHandler<S, A>
): GenericReducer<S, A> => {
    return (state: S = initialState, action: A): S => handlers[action.type]?.(state, action) || state
}

export default reducerFactory
```

---

This is the (simplified) structure inside `store/loading`:

*actions.ts*

```js
import { LoadingToken } from './'

export enum LoadingActions {
    ADD_LOADING_TOKEN = 'ADD_LOADING_TOKEN',
    REMOVE_LOADING_TOKEN_WITH_KEY = 'REMOVE_LOADING_TOKEN_WITH_KEY',
}

export interface AddLoadingTokenAction {
    type: typeof LoadingActions.ADD_LOADING_TOKEN
    payload: LoadingToken
}

export interface RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction {
    type: typeof LoadingActions.REMOVE_LOADING_TOKEN_WITH_KEY
    payload: string
}

type Actions = AddLoadingTokenAction | RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction

export default Actions
```

*handler.addLoadingTokenHandler.ts*

```js
import { LoadingState } from './'
import { AddLoadingTokenAction } from './actions'
import { GenericReducer } from '../reducerFactory'
    
const addLoadingToken: GenericReducer<LoadingState, AddLoadingTokenAction> = (state, action): LoadingState => {
    return {
        ...state,
        loadingTokens: [...state.loadingTokens, action.payload],
    }
}
    
export { addLoadingToken }
```

*handler.removeLoadingTokenWithKey.ts*

```js
import { LoadingState } from './'
import { GenericReducer } from '../reducerFactory'
import { RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction } from './actions'

const removeLoadingTokenWithKey: GenericReducer<LoadingState, RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction> = (
    state,
    action: RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction
) => ({
    ...state,
    loadingTokens: [...state.loadingTokens].filter(loadingToken => loadingToken.key !== action.payload),
})

export { removeLoadingTokenWithKey }
```

*index.ts*

```js
import Actions, { LoadingActions } from 'store/Loading/actions'
import { ActionHandler } from '../reducerFactory'
import { addLoadingToken } from './handler.addLoadingToken'
import { removeLoadingTokenWithKey } from './handler.removeLoadingTokenWithKey'
import reducerFactory from '../reducerFactory'

export interface LoadingToken {
    key: string
    scope: string
    message: string
}

export interface LoadingState {
    loadingTokens: LoadingToken[]
}

const initialLoadingState: LoadingState = {
    loadingTokens: [],
}

const loadingHandlers: ActionHandler<LoadingState, Actions> = {
    [LoadingActions.ADD_LOADING_TOKEN]: addLoadingToken,
    [LoadingActions.REMOVE_LOADING_TOKEN_WITH_KEY]: removeLoadingTokenWithKey,
}

const loadingReducer = reducerFactory<LoadingState, Actions>(initialLoadingState, loadingHandlers)

export default loadingReducer
```

And here is the Problem: Whenever I want to assign `addLoadingToken` or `removeLoadingToken` to the `loadingHandlers` I get a type error from typescript saying:

```
TS2418: Type of computed property's value is 'GenericReducer<LoadingState, AddLoadingTokenAction>', which is not assignable to type 'GenericReducer<LoadingState, Actions>'.
```

Thats because I use the `AddLoadingTokenAction` and `RemoveLoadingTokenWithKeyAction` inside the handlers to avoid `union discrimination` within the handlers.

If anyone with expert knowledge of typescript could help me with this or could point me into the right direction to solve this problem I would be very glad!

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: As requested from @captain-yossarian here is a link to a merged versiopn in typescript playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECcFMBMFcGNLgGIEN4BcD24CeA6DAZwChIAPABxw1AEsA7DJAM3UlAEFM6sGAJVA2gAbJAB4AygBouAPlABvEqFWgA2ugy8GAFVyVIALlBEM4RgHMAuiYDikBkjrwASjAQSZ8kgF8SZFQ0oBgGHA5OFm4eiOBSspwKALygABRmqMwm3lo6JpwAlKBJCpIB8HxmEDFIaJg4uMWg8VygFMzCREohYSZmFgyWoL5yqSpqjHTaqCKSGJnGoDLjqgAWQqJIRPk8fILCYnHeiSQF9o7O0XCxLYnFCspq1Riw4AxpGVlLTZPTs-PMWS5Pj5M7fEqgdYHLaaXYMQhhawAfnw6QBkCBcKKAB9saZ0X4AhRqOBaNBIGxYCJaFBrrUtA0AiBQMCGERCKRicFHLAALagAAyWFQ0Cs3G0lSUKy4ABEZQB9AUAeU4MoAkgA5Ozy3RKgDSAFENU0AOSqhXK1Wa7W6w0ak3SaWuA0AWSVADUDYqVeqtTr9Ub5QB1NW6fjyw0ATVNzrdnu9Vr9tsDIbDEYNkYdhMCJNojGY4DYiC40GgQpFVl0WAA1o5xTopU9QoYTM3IFgWILhaLBvXKvhzQnfTaAxrpZRULgRN2TOWe5Yq7WGNmuaT6ExWOxQO5eVgAG6QOeVmuOINTVZ6yC4PvvR5qNutsIdrsV3tw9mxj1ey3D-124OhuGUbjpO04in05hWNmbZcO%20TScKWR6DIudZwqAeI7vuh7dseS5nhgF5XjeTJgFCmzgPgIpljhyEnvCxAkBUbK0FRSELnR5yRC47h0nEbFzAsCSITR7FLjeyQfOimISgwYL8ei9yNmoUAvG8SlPKo%20BaZ8GLSk8YHzihbImOoWn4Dp%20AGbhjhENJOj4BOU7dtYjpPP4-g5sEigssJr6iY4wwkZCGyHPgUC7gebFGfhhEEAxTFVOFWFRXRMWXrgnGXDxnh8SJAmAtukARdhfnRee6XiU0YxPDprlqKyJiYZFIllQRFVwqcimpHemnaVJ0pWbRS7bBoZkWYN-lstY%20AsHQ1JIKkE1GYpS10fgtaNAAhEkKSsg5oHdgUjq%20AURJBGu3lJc1pWpeVV6BSQzKMOS5Acp5a75puxYpUu6mgBtEEDJY0pEBULb4kD0q8pARBEKgliLP0UEeaueYboWW7yQsf2rcNs4tXR6jWNmCVo1MdAzFjXxUxwKQ9aAuM2SZLkk5UtATfs5EjTenOHOINMJO%20En0%20obE3uyg4-taf5GrYPnUTdS51aoosieL%20CfvGUtJqOAFplGctXSVhm3W1V7HeUbMMyJ2WxE0tI5XU2B4PzeVSbBMlEKMvwUyIAvW35vNbAUQA)

Comment: If you will merge this code into one file and publish it on TypeScript playground, I will try to help you

Comment: Thanks ... I have added a link to a playground

Comment: I think this repo has the configuration you want to implement https://github.com/januswel/react-native-web-sample/tree/master/modules/client/src/modules

Comment: Just in case that is interesting for you: Shortly after that article you linked to was written, the official redux toolkit was released, which will probably solve most of your problems without having to write all that code on your own - it will especially reduce your TypeScript significantly. Please check out [this chapter of the redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux).

Comment: Hello @phry ... thanks for linking that article. It is indeed very interesting and I will definitely give it a try in another project. For this specific project I will stick to the solution provided by diedu for now, since restructuring the code in this massive scale (the sample above is only a tiny slice of the complete redux implementation). Thanks for the heads up anyways! It really looks helpful! 

Comment: @MichelEngelen just to add this info: you do not need to do a full "big bang" migration to redux toolkit. You can slowly replace whatever you come over - and if going full "createSlice" is too big of a change, you can also go "createAction" and "createReducer" and get the same TypeScript benefits you'd have otherwise.